# Is there a way to search ALL Javascripts variables with a specific value?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

I am trying to reverse engineer a fairly complex webpage in Chrome to figure out where a specific known value is coming from... in other words, which variable(s) of which script(s) (many of which are third party) contain the value. I know you can search all loaded scripts for var names in Firebug... I am specifically looking for the VALUES... the var name(s) are the unknowns here.

I would expect some kind of list or table containing var names and the script they came from which contain the value in question.

(And yes, I can imagine some horrific javascript solution, traversing all the Objects in Window, but figured I'd ask first to see if anybody knows a better solution.)

Is such a thing even possible? Doesnt HAVE to be Chrome, its just the browser I am using.

Comment: Even if you had access to all that information, the value could simply not be in any variable, it could come from an expression of literally any kind.

Comment: I don't think so. If I make a variable in a closure then that value is not accessible from outside the closure.

Comment: You might try a heap snapshot